# categories li style edite in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, themes

I wanna change li style of categories that are created using this code:

`<?php wp_list_categories('show_count=0&title_li=');  ?>`

But I wanna give li  my own classes because I use Bootstrap classes,
and my li html code should be:

```
<li class="nav-item bold"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">اتصل بنا</a> </li>
```

I wanna my categories list loop in this code.

I tried to get the classes from inspect from the browser and I got this code:

```
<li class="cat-item cat-item-3"><a href="http://localhost/wp/category/%d8%aa%d8%b5%d9%86%d9%8a%d9%81-%d8%b1%d9%82%d9%85-3/">تصنيف رقم 3</a>
```

I tried to edit cat-item and cat-item-3 but I got nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a custom walker to change the output on each `<li>`.

This goes in `functions.php`:

```
class Walker_Category_Bootstrap_Nav extends Walker_Category {

  function start_lvl( &$output, $depth=0, $args=array() ) {
    // add any custom ul classes here
    $output .= "\n<ul>\n";
  }

  function end_lvl( &$output, $depth=0, $args=array() ) {
    $output .= "</ul>\n";
  }

  function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth=0, $args=array(),$current_object_id = 0 ) {
    // add any custom li and a classes here
    $output .= '<li class="nav-item bold"><a class="nav-link" href="' . home_url( 'category/'.$item->slug ) . '">
    ' . esc_attr( $item->name );
  }

  function end_el( &$output, $item, $depth=0, $args=array() ) {
    $output .= "</a></li>\n";
  }

}
```

And use this in your template:

```
$custom_walker = new Walker_Category_Bootstrap_Nav();

wp_list_categories( array(
  'walker' => $custom_walker,
  'show_count' => 0,
  'title_li' => '',
) );
```

This code is untested, but should be pretty close to what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

i got it 
i call the categories by id then make array  and foreach then echo the code with my li style

```
<?php $category_ids = get_all_category_ids(); ?>
<?php
$args = array(
'orderby' => 'slug',
'parent' => 0
);
$categories = get_categories( $args );
foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
echo '<li class="nav-item bold"><a class="nav-link" href="' . 
get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '"><i class="ss-icon" aria-
hidden="true">' . $category->name . '</i>' . '' . $category->description . '</a></li>';
}
?>
```

and thanks for helping me :)